# MYSQL Server fails to start with no logs - Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, owncloud, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu in WSL on Windows 10.

I'm trying to get an owncloud server going but I've been unable to get mysql working.

When I run `sudo service mysql start` it takes it's time before reporting: `[Fail]` with no other output:

[image: start results]

I tried checking the logs but there are no mysql related logs in `/var/log/`. No folders or files related to mysql at all.

`/etc/mysql/my.conf` includes:

```
[mysqld_safe]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

[mysqld]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

dmesg has nothing in it with mysql, cnf, or mariadb.

### Things I've tried

1. `Adding innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M` to the my.cnf file - Resulted in `Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!`
2. Verified that there are no symlink issues with my.cnf
3. Ran fresh reinstall of mysql

Comment: Please be accurate in describing the name of your my.cnf.  You may edit your question to get it right.  Then I will remove this comment.   Please post the complete content of your my.cnf for review.  You may want to consider using /var/log/mysql/mysql-general.log for the filename to be more descriptive. Thanks

Comment: When in /var/log/  you must make a folder/directory for mysql/ and grant premissions to be used.   Then you have an environment with a prayer of having files to be viewed.